# Settings missing from the add new post page

Tags: posts

It has been a while since I used WordPress and it seems that lot have changed.
It appears that I cannot see certain settings anymore, like set tags, set categories for a post, permalink and more.

Can you help me finding them please ? Below you have a screenshot of what I see right now on the right side when I want to write an article.

[image]

Comment: In the new editor, the Permalink does not show up until a draft is saved. You can either save a draft or publish, and either will then show the permalink as editable. Less than ideal, and there is a GitHub ticket where they're discussing whether or not they can change this so you can set the permalink before publishing or saving a draft.

Comment: I think the most important are the tags and categories, rather than the permalink. It would be nice to have them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable it for screen options above if still not works you can install the [classic editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) to go back to old wordpress admin editor

Comment: Thank you for much for this, did not knew about it. Will definitely use it until they will figure everything out.